# How do i get a subscriber count from youtube api by channel name

Tags: node.js, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to use youtube's api to get the subscriber count of a channel by it's channel name using node.js. How do i do that?

Comment: Check the [channels.list method](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list)  check part statistics   check the [node.js quickstart](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/nodejs)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [official YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) **channels.list** method to get statistics like: subscriberCount, videoCount and viewCount.

| Get statistics from a YouTube channel | [<kbd>Run in Fusebit [image]</kbd>](https://api.us-west-1.on.fusebit.io/v1/run/sub-c2eaf0578e7140ca/share/share/edit?integrationId=so-70714671) |
| --- | --- |

```js
const youtube = googleClient.youtube('v3');
const channelName = 'GoogleDevelopers';
const channelsResponse = await youtube.channels.list({
  part: 'id,statistics',
  forUsername: channelName,
});

if (channelsResponse.data.items && channelsResponse.data.items.length) {
  const { statistics: { subscriberCount, videoCount, viewCount } } = channelsResponse.data.items[0];
  console.log(`The channel ${channelName} has ‍‍ ${subscriberCount} subscribers,  ${videoCount} videos and  ${viewCount} views.`);
} else {
  console.log = `Channel not found: ${channelName}`;
}
```

[Update]

Based on the comments, here is an example of how to search for a channel based on a search term, then you will use the channel id to get the statistics, from the previous code, instead of sending **forUserName** parameter you will send **id**
[See search API docs here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)

```js
  const channelsResponse = await youtube.search.list({
    part: 'snippet',
    q: searchTerm,
    maxResults: 10,
    type: 'channel',
    order: 'viewCount' // show more popular first
  });
```

This is the [response object](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search#resource) returned by each item from the search

```json
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
  "etag": etag,
  "id": {
    "kind": string,
    "videoId": string,
    "channelId": string,
    "playlistId": string
  },
  "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": datetime,
    "channelId": string,
    "title": string,
    "description": string,
    "thumbnails": {
      (key): {
        "url": string,
        "width": unsigned integer,
        "height": unsigned integer
      }
    },
    "channelTitle": string,
    "liveBroadcastContent": string
  }
}
```

Comment: The forusername input does not work with a channel that had changed it's name like the popular youtube channel "MrBeast". I have tried this with the "Try this api" in the documentation with the channel and showed me a person who had the channel name first. it only showed his channel statistics when I search his original name "mrbeast6000". I am getting input from discord using discord.js the person inputting may not know his original channel name.

Comment: Makes sense, so, If you are building a discord bot you may want to show a list of channels found with the search term first, then allow the user to select the specific channel to get the statistics, otherwise will be hard to guess the channel the user is interested in, I've updated the code with an example how to search for a channel, order by the number of views, so, popular channels will appear first. I can show you a Discord example too but is out of the scope of the original question so I don't want to add it here.

Answer (score 0):

It's more accurate if you can get the channel id:
Then all you need to do is to make a request to Youtube Data V3 API:

Request: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=UC1gi4ynIYAcd_BmFlJsLOWg&key=your_api_key

Response Format:

```
{
    "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
    "etag": "vdXkdxBKA5DKypndZTEWUM_tBPQ",
    "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 1,
        "resultsPerPage": 5
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#channel",
            "etag": "R5sb6hhxom_vkPLE9izol0WBeVg",
            "id": "UC1gi4ynIYAcd_BmFlJsLOWg",
            "statistics": {
                "viewCount": "35960",
                "subscriberCount": "242",
                "hiddenSubscriberCount": false,
                "videoCount": "26"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```